# Add a column of values based on two other columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column to a table where the new column, called "ID", would contain 3-5 or 3.5 or 3/5, if column 1 contains the value 3 and column 2 contains the value 5.

Comment: Ifelse statement would do here: `df$ID <- ifelse(df$col1==3 & df$col2==5, 3/5, 0)`. I set the second argument in the ifelse statement to 0 since you didn't explicitly specify what you want in return when your criteria is not met. I recommend you read up on how to properly post questions on SO. You want to provide some data for us to work with so that people can best help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @biology2021 It would help if you provided a [complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). However, you may be looking for something like: `df$ID <- paste(df[[1]], df[[2]], sep = "-")` if `df` is your data.frame...you could use a different argument for `sep` such as a decimal point, forward slash, etc. if desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(ID = paste0(column1,'-',column2))
```

you can change `-` with any symbol you want.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, an `ifelse`operation will be helpful:

Toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = c(1,3,4,2,6,3,5),
  c2 = c(2,5,3,0,2,5,5)
)

df$ID <- ifelse(df$c1 == 3 & df$c2 == 5,        # condition to meet
                paste(df$c1, df$c2, sep = "/"), # action if condition == TRUE
                NA)                             # action if condition == FALSE
```

Result:

```
df
  c1 c2   ID
1  1  2 <NA>
2  3  5  3/5
3  4  3 <NA>
4  2  0 <NA>
5  6  2 <NA>
6  3  5  3/5
7  5  5 <NA>
```